# Not printing the right output - Arrays and Strings - Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, printing, lines

While I've fixed the split() problem I had earlier (Thanks to the last person who helped me out that is!) I've got another problem. That's obviously obvious in the code listed here, however I don't know what it is. The problem is that it only prints the last line of the file to the output, when, in this stage, I'd like it to print out ALL the lines. What do I need to fix? Thanks!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.String; 
public class Hurricanes2
{

public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException 
{
int counter = 0;
String [] token = new String[1000];
String [] tokenElements = new String[128];
String [] hurrcaneYear = new String[64];
String [] hurrcaneName = new String[64];
int []  hurricaneCategory = new int[64];
double [] hurrcanePressure = new double[64];
double tempKnots;
double knotsToMph; 
double [] hurricaneWindSpeeds = new double[64];
double categoryAverage;
double pressureAverage;
double speedAverage; 
String headerData = "                          Hurricanes 1980 - 2006\n\n Year     Hurricane       Category        Pressure(MB)        Wind Speed (MPH)\n========================================================================";
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("hurcData2.txt"));
System.out.print(headerData);

/**---Use for-each (line:token) 
 * Parse for year - > year array
 * parse for name - > name array
 * parse for knots - > tempKnots
 * knotsToMph = tempKnots  * 1.15078
 * hurricaneWindSpeed[counter] = knotsToMph
 *  enter if-else to calculate category (hurricaneCategory [] = 1,2,3,4, or 5):
 *      74-95 cat1 
 *      96-110 cat2
 *      111 - 129 cat3
 *      130-156 cat4
 *      157 or higher cat 5
 * 
 * 
 */
while(inFile.hasNextLine()) 
{
    token[counter] = inFile.nextLine();
    tokenElements = token[counter].split("  ");
    counter++;
}
int counter2 = 0;
for(String line:tokenElements) 
{
System.out.println(tokenElements[counter2]);
counter2++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the "for loop" within the "while loop.

```
    while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
        token[counter] = inFile.nextLine();
        tokenElements = token[counter].split("  ");
        counter++;

        for(String part:tokenElements){
            System.out.println(part);
        }
   }
```

Comment: That throws an out of bounds exception D:

Answer (score 0):

In that loop:

```
while(inFile.hasNextLine()) 
{
    token[counter] = inFile.nextLine();
    tokenElements = token[counter].split("  ");
    counter++;
}
```

You are replacing `tokenElements` with the elements of the last line read. Then if the "for loop" that follows you seem to think that `tokenElements` contains every line. This is not the case. You should add the last line to a list and then print that list.

So at the beginning you define:

```
List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you modify your "while loop" that way:

```
while(inFile.hasNextLine()) 
{
    token[counter] = inFile.nextLine();
    lines.add(token[counter].split("  "));
    counter++;
}
```

Then you can print all the lines:

```
for (String[] tokenElements : lines) {
     for (String token : tokenElements) {
          System.out.print(token + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

In general, you should use lists that grow up automatically instead of arrays with magical values like `String[128]` and all that.

Comment: write `import java.util.List;` and `import java.util.ArrayList;` at the beginning of your file (before the class declaration). In Eclipse, you can simply do `Ctrl-Shift-O`. You should look at a few tutorial about collections also, it is very useful.

Comment: The fact that you don't know how to import List and ArrayList make me think you are still learning the language. I reiterate that you should read some tutorials to give you the understanding of the basics. Look for example at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html

Comment: If I don't provide a "magical value" the IDE will give me the error "Variable might not have been initialized"

Comment: That's normal, you should learn to use List and use that intead :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use foreach you don't have to use the counter:

```
for(String line : tokenElements) {
   System.out.println(line);         
}
```

That being said, you overwrite tokenElements in your while loop with the latest, hence only the last line is printed out, because your tokenElements consists of the words of only one line.

You can actually skip the "split" part, and skip the second counter ;-) :

```
while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(inFile.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: I need to split it so that I can have my elements in the line go to each array. A line looks like this: year(tab)name(tab)Speed(tab)Pressure.